# check db and return result

Tags: asp.net

I am simply trying to check db to see if user is friends with other user

in controller

```
    [NonAction]
    public bool IsFriend(int UserId, int id)
    {
            int query = _service.IsFriend(UserId, id);
            if (query > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
```

this will work if I can pass the correct parameters for it

how could i use this from the view where i have data. I know its not  great id eg

IsFriend(User.Id, Model.Userid)

model.userid is friend checking
userid is id of signed in user

is this even possible to do this from a view?

using razor cshmtl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may move the method to a more common place ( may be a helper class ) and then add a `using` statement in your view and call the function

```
@model YourPageViewModel

@using YourProject.HelperNameSpaceName
<div>  
  @foreach(var friend in Model.KnownPeople)
  {
    <p>@friend.Name</p>
    <p>@(IsFriend(friend.ID, Model.UserId)??"is friend":" is not friend")</p>    
  }
</div>
```

But what i recommend you to do is to do this thing in your action method instead of your view. Just do the check in your Action method and add only the Friend users to your Friends collection property of your view model. Then in the view, simply display it.

```
public ActionMethod Profile(int userId)
{
  var profileViewModel=new ProfileViewModel();
  var knownPeoples=repo.GetAllKnownPeopls(userId);
  foreach(var person in knownPeoples)
  {
    if(IsFriend(person.ID, profileViewModel.CurrentUserID))
      profileViewModel.Friends.Add(person);
  }
  return View(profileViewModel);
}
```

Now in your view, simply write display code only

```
@model ProfileViewModel
@foreach(var friend in Model.Friends)
{
  <p>@friend.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info shy, I ended up putting it inside the action method as you said and it worked perfectly. Thanks :)